# Show loading spinner

Tags: reactjs, axios

## Problem

Right now my code shows a spinner to indicate that I'm still waiting for a response from an API.

I did not consider that while my response is accurate, fast and makes the spinner go away...

The actual rendering of the image is slow.

## Question

How can I display a spinner while the image has not rendered ?

## Code

## Main App

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Users from "./components/Users";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import "./App.css";
import Upload from "./components/Upload";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Mix from "./components/Mix";

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const searchUsers = text => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.giphy.com/v1/stickers/search?q=${text}&api_key=${
          process.env.REACT_APP_GIPHY_CLIENT_ID
        }`
      )
      /* Trigger re-render. The users data will now be present in 
       component state and accessible for use/rendering */
      .then(res => setUsers(res.data.data))
      // log error
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      // set loading finished
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Upload />
      <Search searchUsers={searchUsers} />
      <Mix />
      <div className="ui horizontal inverted divider">
        {" "}
        <i aria-hidden="true" className="youtube icon" />
      </div>
      <div container>
        <Users loading={loading} users={users} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

export default App;
```

## Users Component

```
import React from "react";
import UserItem from "./UserItem";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";

const Users = ({ users, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="ui relaxed five column grid">
        {users.map(user => (
          <UserItem key={user.id} gif={user.images.original.url} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Users;
```

## Spinner Component

```
import React from "react";

const Spinner = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui center aligned fluid container">
      <div className="ui active inline loader" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Spinner;
```

## User Item Component

```
import React from "react";

const UserItem = ({ gif }) => (
  <div className="column">
    <img alt="" src={gif} className="ui image" />
  </div>
);

export default UserItem;
```

Comment: By slow, you mean the image network call. ? If the image is set to an img tag for first time, that is when it is downloaded. If that is your issue, you can try to preload the required images using js and css techniques available so that, the moment you set it to an img tag, the image appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [`onLoad`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) method on `img` tag (it is one of the two [image events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#image-events) React supports). When the image finishes loading, the `onLoad` function gets called.

In your `UserItem` component:

```
const UserItem = ({ gif }) => {
  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="column">
      { !imageLoaded && <Spinner />}
      <img alt="" src={gif} className="ui image" onLoad={() => setImageLoaded(true} />
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: awesome...I think this will work for sure__I will verify when I get home